# Returning every possibility of a string using IEnumerable

Tags: vb.net

So i've got the following code, it doesn't fully work correctly, it doesn't return all possible variants.

I need a string such as "now1one" to return every variant possible of the characters i want to check and replace. Characters such as the ones listed in the code below.

```
    Public Iterator Function ParsePlayerNames(ByVal PlayerName As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Try
        Dim i As Integer = PlayerName.IndexOf("O")
        Dim chrType As Char = "O"

        If i = -1 And chrType = "O" Then
            i = PlayerName.IndexOf("o")
            chrType = "o"
        End If

        If i = -1 And chrType = "o" Then
            i = PlayerName.IndexOf("0")
            chrType = "0"
        End If

        If i = -1 And chrType = "0" Then
            i = PlayerName.IndexOf("l")
            chrType = "l"
        End If

        If i = -1 And chrType = "l" Then
            i = PlayerName.IndexOf("1")
            chrType = "1"
        End If

        If i = -1 And chrType = "1" Then
            i = PlayerName.IndexOf("I")
            chrType = "I"
        End If

        If i = -1 And chrType = "I" Then
            Yield PlayerName
            Exit Function
        End If

        Dim base As String = PlayerName.Substring(0, i)
        Dim permutations As IEnumerable(Of String) = Enumerable.Empty(Of String)()

        If PlayerName.Length > i Then
            permutations = ParsePlayerNames(PlayerName.Substring(i + 1))
        End If

        For Each permutation As String In permutations
            If chrType = "O" Or chrType = "o" Or chrType = "0" Then
                Yield base & "O" & permutation
                Yield base & "o" & permutation
                Yield base & "0" & permutation
            End If
            If chrType = "l" Or chrType = "1" Or chrType = "I" Then
                Yield base & "l" & permutation
                Yield base & "1" & permutation
                Yield base & "I" & permutation
            End If
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        OutputError(ex.Message & " - " & ex.StackTrace & vbCrLf)
    End Try
End Function
```

Right now, it returns all variants handling the "o"s in the string, but not returning variants that include "o"s and "1"s, such as returning the string "n0wIone".

Any ideas on how to clean this up and get it to actually return all possible variants? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it using a debugger to see where it diverges from your expectations?

Comment: Yes, so lets say i pass the string "lol" into the function, it will only give me the variants of the last two characters in that string, while returning the first character as always "l". When i step through it, it seems to skip over the first "l" because it will recognize the "o" first due to how the end if statements are arranged.

Answer (score 0):

Under the Tools menu select Nuget Manager then Mangage Nuget Packages for Solution. Select Browse on the left top. Search for Combinatorics. Install the package.

There is a page describing the use of this library at https://trycatch.me/combinatorics-in-net-part-i-permutations-combinations-variations/

```
Imports Combinatorics.Collections

Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim CArray As Char() = "now1one".ToCharArray
    Dim c As New Combinations(Of Char)(CArray, 3)
    Debug.Print("Combinations of 3 Characters")
    For Each v In c
        Debug.Print(String.Join(",", v))
    Next
    Dim ps As New Permutations(Of Char)(CArray)
    Debug.Print("Permutations of Input string")
    For Each p In ps
        Debug.Print(String.Join(",", p))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using anymore packages with this current project, unless absolutely needed. Is there a quick fix to the above code to solve the issue?